# React + Typescript : TypeScript error: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'CSSProperties'

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am using Typescript with React and is currently facing the issue

[image: Error in Compiling]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `style` attribute expects an object with style properties rather than a string:

```
style={{
    backgroundImage: "url('https://source.unsplash.com/07fzqFEfLlo/1920x1080')"
}}
```

[See the React docs on the subject.](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)